# How to fix overlap labels on y-axis - Latex

Tags: latex, tikz

I create a simple diagram in Latex (tikzpicture) and some labels on the y-axis overlap as you can see in the picture

[image]

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      title=\textbf{example},
      ybar,
      width=10cm, height=5cm, bar width=30pt,
      enlargelimits=0.5,
      symbolic x coords={2013,2014,2015,2016}, xtick={2013,2014,2015,2016},
      ytick=data,
      ]
      \addplot coordinates
      {(2013,794) (2014,1208) (2015,1183) (2016,1259)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

How can I fix this, I don't want to make the diagram much higher?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to trust `pgfplots` to create readable axis labels instead of manually interfering:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      title=\textbf{example},
      ybar,
      width=10cm, height=5cm, bar width=30pt,
      enlargelimits=0.5,
      symbolic x coords={2013,2014,2015,2016}, xtick={2013,2014,2015,2016},
%      ytick=data,
      ]
      \addplot coordinates
      {(2013,794) (2014,1208) (2015,1183) (2016,1259)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really need to show the exact numerical values, a plot might not be the suitable form of visualization and a table might be better suited.